# Angular.js with rails: only one directive is executed on element in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have Rails 4 project with angular.js and I faced with a problem, only first directive on element work.

my gemset include:

```
gem "angularjs-rails", '~> 1.2.22'
gem 'slim', :git => 'git://github.com/brennancheung/slim.git', :branch => 'angularjs_support'
gem 'coffee-rails'
```

and when I try to do something like:

```
html ng-app="app"
...
div ng-controller='TestCtr'
  a ng-mouseover="test(1)" ng-mouseleave="test(2)" ng-click="test(3)" href="#/" Home


@app = angular.module('app', [])
@app.controller 'testCtr', ($scope)->
  $scope.test = (i) ->
    console.log(i)
```

only ng-mouseover="test(1)" work, if I`ll remove first directive then second ng-mouseleave="test(2)" will work and ng-click will not.

It is strange but this behavior actual only for google chrome, I've tested this in Safari, Opera, and Firefox and everything is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

([Answered in a question edit- converted to a community wiki answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))

The OP wrote:

> It is strange but this behaviour actual only found for google chrome, I've tested this in Safari, Opera, and Firefox and everything is just fine.
>   At last found the reason, it was google chrome extension Batarang that caused that strange issue.